# Why does my chart print the wrong model for Variable Importance?

Tags: r, charts, markdown, random-forest

This seems like a really obvious question, but I've checked through the code and it seems fine.  The challenge is that the code runs fine when run line by line but when using the knitting the R markdown document, it picks up the wrong Random Forest and prints the importance for that.
I've tried reinstalling knitr but that hasn't worked.

The data is based on the train titanic [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data)

I have 2 models, one called modRF and another mod2.  I want to run the chart on mod 2, but the output is modRF.
You can see this by changing the line
`imp<-importance(mod2$finalModel)` to be modRF$...
Like I say when I run this code line by line, it works, in Rmarkdown (knitting to HTML) it generates the wrong chart.  Can someone elaborate?

PS the random forest models take less than a minute to run each on my machine so running this code shouldn't take you too long.

Thanks in advance for your help,
J

Here's my code to replicate

````
suppressMessages(library(caret))
suppressMessages(library(randomForest))
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressMessages(library(ggplot2))
setwd("~/Kaggle/Titanic")

totaltrain<-read.csv("train.csv")

#Adding features for EDA
totaltrain$CabinYes<-as.numeric(!(totaltrain$Cabin)=="")
ageid<-data.frame("minage"=c(0,20,30,40,50,60),
                  "AgeLabel"=c("Under 20","20-30","30-40","40-50","50-60","60+"))
#vlookup TRUE equivalent
totaltrain$AgeBracket<-ageid[findInterval(totaltrain$Age,ageid$minage),2]
        #findInterval creates an index of which of the initial values most closely matches
        #the lookup... Then use with the age id index and return the second column
a<-c(1,2,3,5,7,8,12,13,14)
rates<-totaltrain[,a]
rates$AgeBracket<-as.character(rates$AgeBracket)
rates$AgeBracket[is.na(rates$AgeBracket)]<-"Unknown"
rates$AgeBracket<-as.factor(rates$AgeBracket)

rates$Survived<-as.factor(rates$Survived)
rates$Pclass<-as.factor(rates$Pclass)
rates$CabinYes<-as.factor(rates$CabinYes

```{r,cache=TRUE}
set.seed(4321)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=rates$Survived,
                               p=0.75, list=FALSE)
training<-rates[inTrain,]
testing<-rates[-inTrain,]
modRF<-train(Survived~.-PassengerId,data=training,method="rf",trControl=
                     trainControl(method="cv",number = 3, 
                                  allowParallel = T,))
pred<-predict(modRF,newdata=testing)
testing$PredRight<-pred==testing$Survived
sum(testing$PredRight)/length(pred)
```

b<-c(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,12,13)
rates2<-totaltrain[,b]
rates2$Age[is.na(rates2$Age)]<-0
#Model 2
set.seed(2072)

inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=rates$Survived,
                               p=0.75, list=FALSE)
training<-rates[inTrain,]
testing<-rates[-inTrain,]
mod2<-train(Survived~.-PassengerId,data=training,method="rf",trControl=
                     trainControl(method="cv",number = 3, 
                                  allowParallel = T,))
imp<-importance(mod2$finalModel)
impdf<-data.frame(Variables=row.names(imp),Importance=round(imp[,1],2))
rankimp<-impdf %>% mutate(Rank = paste0('#',dense_rank(-Importance)))
ggplot(rankimp, aes(x = reorder(Variables, Importance), 
                           y = Importance, fill = Importance)) +
        geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
        geom_text(aes(x = Variables, y = 0.5, label = Rank),
                  hjust=0, vjust=0.55, size = 4, colour = 'red') +
        labs(x = 'Variables') +
        coord_flip()
````

Comment: For those that have looked at this, can you repeat the error?